# Add input lines subset to prefix shell script output

Tags: bash, shell

I have a complex shell script(`check_axfr.sh`) to check whether a domain is vulnerable to DNS Zone Transfer vulnerability. It takes only a `single domain` as `argument` to check whether that domain is vulnerable or not.

Example :

```
#./check_axfr.sh example.com
```

If it is vulnerable in any of the `name servers` of the domain,It will yield the following result.

```
DOMAIN example.com: ns0.example.com. Vulnerable
DOMAIN example.com: ns1.example.com. Not Vulnerable
```

For checking multiple domains, I kept all the list of domains(100) in a file `Input.txt`.

```
example.com
abc.com
mno.com
xyz.com
prq.com
.......
```

I tried,

```
for i in $(cat Input.txt);do sh check_axfr.sh $i;done
```

Now,my Input file ( `Input.txt`) will now contain `number,domain`

```
1,example.com
2,abc.com
3,mno.com
4,xyz.com
5,prq.com
.........
```

I would like to get output as ,

```
1,DOMAIN example.com: ns0.example.com. Vulnerable
1,DOMAIN example.com: ns1.example.com. Not Vulnerable
2,DOMAIN abc.com    : ns1.abc.com. Not Vulnerable  
3,DOMAIN mno.com    : .............
4,DOMAIN xyz.com    : .............
5,DOMAIN prq.com    : .............
```

I'm not familiar in shell scripting & I don't wish to alter the parent script , Can some one help me on how to achieve this ?

Comment: `Bash` and other shells can trim the leading characters of a string held in a variable. Instead of `$i` use `"${i#*,}"`; it should remove any leading character up to a comma. For instance, when `i='34,gog.com'`, `"${i#*,}"` is `gog.com`. Read [Shell Parameter Expansion section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in bash manual pages.

Comment: BashFAQ #1 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 -- would be a good place to start.

Comment: The original title ("shell script issue") did not describe the question in any useful way (literally, any question tagged "shell" could have that same title and it would be just as descriptive). I've tried to make it more useful, but *because* it was initially unclear, it's hard to be certain that I've done so accurately. @Arun, please check and correct.

Comment: BTW, as an aside -- it's not good practice to use extensions such as `.sh` or `.bash` on executable scripts. For executables, their filename is the name of the command used to run them; including the language in the filename means you can't rewrite the script in a different language without making the name misleading or changing all callers. Also, it's simply not convention: You run `ls`, not `ls.elf`.

Comment: ...the only place where `.sh`, `.ksh`, or `.bash`, etc **is** appropriate is a script that's expected to be sourced into a shell, not executed in its own interpreter. This common for shell libraries, for instance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks mate for correcting the questions. Got the key points you have said !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind installing an extra tool, you can also use `parallel` to do this with one single command (and obviously running jobs in parallel mode instead of the default serial one):

```
parallel -C',' --keep-order './check.axfr.sh "{2}" | sed "s/^/{1}, /"' < Input.txt
```

**Breakout**

```
parallel 
  -C ','                  # use comma as column separator of each input line
  --keep-order            # keep the same order in the output
  './check.axfr.sh "{2}"  # execute per job the check.axfr.sh passing domain column
  | sed "s/^/{1}, /"'     # Add the first column (number) before each line 
                          # of the output of the script
  < Input.txt  # load lines from Input.txt file
```

**Output**

> 1, DOMAIN domain1.com: ns0.example.com. Vulnerable
>   1, DOMAIN domain1.com: ns1.example.com. Not Vulnerable
>   2, DOMAIN domain2.com: ns0.example.com. Vulnerable
>   2, DOMAIN domain2.com: ns1.example.com. Not Vulnerable
>   3, DOMAIN domain3.com: ns0.example.com. Vulnerable
>   3, DOMAIN domain3.com: ns1.example.com. Not Vulnerable
>   4, DOMAIN domain4.com: ns0.example.com. Vulnerable
>   4, DOMAIN domain4.com: ns1.example.com. Not Vulnerable

**NOTE**

If you want to spare some bits, with `parallel` you can remove the `number` column at all from the input file and use this:

```
parallel --keep-order './check.axfr.sh "{}" | sed "s/^/{#}, /"' < Input.txt
```

Where `{#}` is the id number of the job executed. The output will be  identical.

Comment: Thanks for your clear solution. I cannot ignore the number in the column as it would give me better understanding of which ID is vulnerable when shown in stdout.

Comment: @Arun: glad to hear that! The last command is an optional way to obtain exactly the same output you require without the needs of the line number you put in the first file (each line is processed by a different job identified by a progressive number  ``{#}`` so the result is equivalent to the number of line you put in the ``Input.txt`` file). With the same input file try ``parallel -C',' --keep-order './check.axfr.sh "{2}" | sed "s/^/{#}, /"' < Input.txt``: you obtain the same output without using the numbers column. Anyway, this is only an extra point of view and not required

Comment: Yeah,Got noted down dude ! Thanks any way.

Answer (score 3):

Read the line of the input and split on `,` to get the parts of an input line. Call `check.axfr.sh` using the second part, the domain:

```
# wrapper.sh    
while IFS=, read -r id domain
do
    result=$(./check.axfr.sh "$domain")
    echo "$id,$result"
done
```

Usage:

```
$ bash wrapper.sh < Input.txt
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Quotes won't hurt. But the input of domain names will probably not create problems with missing quotes.

Comment: If we expect input to be within its intended domain, yes. That's not a good practice -- the biggest data loss incident I've seen at one of my employers was because of lack of quoting which the authors considered not to matter because the input "couldn't" be anything but hex characters -- until there was a buffer overflow in the program that generated that input...

Comment: This is trivial but in the output only the first line of each domain is preceded by the number. e.g. ``1,DOMAIN  domain1.com: ns0.example.com. Vulnerable\n DOMAIN  domain1.com: ns1.example.com. Not Vulnerable``